# Find if element contains element with id

Tags: angular, jasmine

How can I find if an element contains an element with a specified id?

```
<div class="menu">
  <div id="signin">Sign in</div>
</div>
```

I'm checking by query length here but thought there might be a better way:

```
it('Main menu has signin link if not signed in', () => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    let links = menuElemDebug.queryAll(By.css('#signin-button'));
    expect(links.length).toBe(1);
})
```

Comment: You can use `expect(fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('#signin')).toBeTruthy()`

Answer (score 0):

Try a simple css selection like:

```
let links = menuElemDebug.queryAll(By.css('.menu> #signin'));
```

But if you are going after an element with an id, I guess its already uniquely identified.

Comment: do i need the .menu> if my menuElemDebug has already filtered out the rest of the document?

Comment: Well you don't but you were asking: `How can I find if an element contains an element with a specified id?`

Answer (score -1):

```
if(('#signin').parentNode==('.menu'))
  {
   }
```

I hope it helps. Let me know if this don't works.

And another method would be

```
var parent = document.querySelector('.menu'),
child = document.querySelector('#signin');
if (parent.contains(child)) {
// .. it's a child}
```

Comment: ffs i'm not using jquery

Comment: Sorry my bad. But its just two statement and go. Love js.